# High Frequency Oscillations on Mosfet Gate

Tags: mosfet, rf, simulation, resonance, oscillation

I am working on a circuit that drives an inductor at its resonant frequency. However certain models of MOSFET I simulate the circuit with experience oscillations at the MOSFET gates as pictured below. Several other models of MOSFET I have tried this simulation with do not experience these oscillations while others do despite minimal difference between them.

[image: Mosfet Gate Oscillations]

[image: Circuit Schematic]

These high-frequency oscillations then lead to a small amount of undesired current flowing through L1. The snubber comprised of R4 and C4 has reduced them to the size currently pictured but not eliminate them.

[image: Current through L1]

Essentially my question is how can I eliminate these oscillations on my MOSFET gates?

Note that the MOSFETS are being switched by feedback from L2, not the 555 timer. It is not necessary and can be ignored.

Comment: That's *ringing*, not oscillation. There's a difference. Ringing can still be a problem, though.

Comment: That's on the drain, coupled to the gate by capacitance (and weak gate drive). Increase R4 to 4.7 ohms.

Comment: What an ugly and unhelpful way to draw MOSFETs.